# How to use flask configuration in instance folder and basedir

Tags: python, flask

I have the following flask app:

main.py

```
from application import create_app    
app = create_app('flask.cfg')
```

application/**init**.py

```
def create_app(config_filename=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)
```

instance/flask.cfg

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get(
    'DATABASE_URL') or 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'database/app.db')
```

My problem with this setup: basedir resolves to the instance folder and not to the basedir of my project where my database folder is located.
Whats the best way to handle this?

Comment: Don't pass in a filename. Just import the config file like an object.

Answer (score 4):

`__file__` is the same directory that your file is in.

You used `__file__` in `instance/flask.cfg` so it refers to `instance/` where `flask.cfg` is!

All you need is going one step back to your project directory cause
your `main.py` is in the project directory

You need to do something like this:

```
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('../', os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Also this will work

```
basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: this feel ... wrong ;) but the only solution i can think of without some "hidden python magic i don't know yet"

Comment: it does work. but using .. in order to ascend the folder structure is ... quite basic ;) i was hoping for something like "flask.home" or something like that.
But of course, your answer is correct.

Comment: @Dakkar I was looking for something like that too, you're right, its weird, I tried to get the dirname of that dirname, but it returns the same thing..

Comment: @Dakkar Updated, this one is better, Django Settings uses this method